# BorPred in local iisexpress - is it memory leak?

Tags: mdriven

I've installed BorPred in local iisexpress on clean server 2019 core. Debug  in web.config is disabled,  log4net setup changed to show only ERROR/FATAL. 
Borpred started with mem usage less than 20M, and then I connect to it mem usage start growing and this is ok.
If I leave borpred alone for 1 hour it keeps running and it is normal too due to the  periodic api/admin_WebApi/GetChangesSince calls. 
But the mem usage after 1 hour increased up to 600M
I use TASKLIST command to check it.
Question - is it normal behavior or it can be mem leak? 
Are there some settings to change/to check that can help to decrease mem usage?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New name for this product is MDrivenServer.
The MDrivenServer has client synchronization - this builds up a list of changed identities. It will be expected to see a build up of memory due to update operations building the memory of the recently changed objects.

The MDrivenServer also has internal EcoSpaces to handle its own administration and ServerSide jobs - these will be garbaged and recreated when used a certain period of time.

.NET does not necessarily release memory from processes that have shown a need for the memory in the past - this causes you to see the used memory to equal the worst case need - like if you have a server-side job that pushes memory usage and it run once a day - the memory usage may still reflect the max usage.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Some comments: I used the example model without serverside jobs, and did not change it during the tests. I made initial kick of MDrivenServer via https and left MDriven Server alone for few hours. And it seems that this behaviour was related to the blocking access to the "portal.mdriven.net" from my server. When I open this access memory usage stopped growing.

Comment: Hmm - ok - will check that use case. Maybe it was the log of failed attempts that used up memory. We use log4net and spool log to disk - but it stays in memory for a while.

Comment: Hello Hans, please do not waste your time. I've completed additional tests - the source of my problems is IISExpress version. I used 64 bits version - memory usage grows abnormally. When I swithced to 32 bit version everything became ok - 120 Mb for the process and it is cool! thanks a lot!

Comment: udate: who is using the iisexpress 64 bits version on the servercore the workaround is to add two lines gcServer enabled="false" gcConcurrent enabled="false" in to the C:\Users\UserName\Documents\IISExpress\config\Aspnet.config file. It helped me to reduce the iisexpress.exe mem usage to 80Mb + increased the MDrivenServer response time